# Finding POST variable without apostrophe in code

Tags: php

I have a PHP application and since upgrading to PHP 8. I have discovered that in some random locations I have forgot to put apostrophe in some variable names so for example it should be:

```
$POST['VariableName']
```

But I have accidently put it as

```
$POST[VariableName]
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant
```

And for some reason in previous PHP versions it just worked without breaking. However, in PHP 8, it's not liking it. And I'm just not sure how I can go through so many files to look for this. Is there a way where I can maybe write a PHP code to go through a file and look for this error? or possibly use NotePad++ ?

Help and suggestions would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "not liking it"...means what exactly? Are you getting a specific error message or other unexpected behaviour? Please ensure we have a clear description of the problem and a [mre] including relevant code in context. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson — [Attempting to access unqualified constants which are undefined. Previously, unqualified constant accesses resulted in a warning and were interpreted as strings.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php) … but the question is asking how using an IDE to pattern match across multiple files so they can find all instances of the error and fix it, not about the error itself, so I'd give them a pass on not describing it in detail.

Comment: @ADyson the error I am getting is Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant

Comment: @Quentin that's correct, I am not trying to debug the error. I just want to know if there is a way to easily find these mistakes in my code and replace it with correct format

Comment: Decent editors/IDEs have a "regexp search" where you can search/replace using a regular expression

Comment: You can try PHP Storm, which is a decent editor that has the regexp search mentioned by brombeer